# Printing List Object in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm getting close to printing objects in a table in JSP that was passed from a Servlet, however, they are not printing for some reason.

I have confirmed the servlet actually does save the data into the list but i have not confirmed whether the list was passed successfully to the JSP or if its i made a mistake with the printing of the objects.

Here is my code for the JSP page(listProduct is the list passed from the Servlet):

```
<% List newList = (List)session.getAttribute("listProduct");%>

        <c:forEach  items="${listProduct}" var="Product">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${Product.productId}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.productType}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.productPrice}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.vendorName}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.productName}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.productDescription}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${product.stockLevel}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="action" /></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/edit?id=<c:out value='${product.productId}' />">Edit</a>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="/delete?id=<c:out value='${product.prodictId}' />">Delete</a>                     
                </td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Also my "newList" in the JSP is unused however other tutorials had that in and even when I try to use the newList for the table it doesnt register and it still says that newList is unused.

Any pointers or help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: More information (Servlet code)

I have included my servlet code that is creating the list and sending it to the jsp page as well - just incase the problem is from there.

```
    List<Product> listProduct = db.listProducts();

            request.setAttribute("listProduct", listProduct);
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("displayProduct.jsp");
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**db is the DAO. 
EDIT 2 DAO code: This code is what is providing the array list to the servlet.

```
 public List<Product> listProducts() throws SQLException {
        List<Product> listProduct = new ArrayList<>();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT";

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            int productId = rs.getInt("productId");
            double productPrice = rs.getDouble("PRODUCTPRICE");
            String productType = rs.getString("productType");
            String vendorName = rs.getString("vendorName");
            String productName = rs.getString("productName");
            String productDescription = rs.getString("productDescription");
            int stockLevel = rs.getInt("stockLevel");

            Product product = new Product(productId, productPrice, productType, vendorName, productName, productDescription, stockLevel);
            listProduct.add(product);

        }

        return listProduct;
```

ANOTHER EDIT!! : 
I confirmed that the issue is with the coding in the JSP table section as the arraylist is successfully sent to the JSP page - but only issue now is printing it in the table per the attribute.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <td>${Product.getProductId()}</td>
```

Just use it without the c:out. 
And sometimes u write product instead of Product

Comment: Are you sure that your List contains some elements? I tried it with an ArrayList<Product>.
What List returns db.listProducts();

Comment: I believe so, I have attached the code from the DAO that makes the original arrays list. Thanks for your help btw